# Clear a public variable in Angular Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular and ran into an issue, google and stack overflow didn't turn up anything useful, I believe largely due to the fact I don't even know what to search for. So here's my problem hoping you could help me resolve. I have the following code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz2zgozx/)

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="reload()">Reload</button>
<button ng-click="loadMore()">Load More</button>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in list">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'mainSvr', function ($scope, mainSvr) {
    $scope.list = mainSvr.list;
    $scope.reload = mainSvr.reload;
    $scope.loadMore = mainSvr.loadMore;
}]);

app.service('mainSvr', function () {
    // private
    var self = this;

    // public
    this.list = [];

    this.reload = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            self.list.push(i * 10);
        }
    };

    this.loadMore = function () {
        var listLength = self.list.length;
        for (var i = listLength; i < listLength + 5; i++) {
            self.list.push(i * 10);
        }
    }
});
```

When I click on reload I want to clear and re-populate the list (so it shows 0-40 again), how do I do it?
I tried:

```
this.reload = function () {
    self.list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.list.push(i * 10);
    }
};
```

But it didn't work, nothing show up at all. I use debugger and break point and saw that the list is actually cleared and re-populated, somehow the UI doesn't pick it up when I do self.list = []; Please help me understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset *existing* array instead of overwriting array reference with new one. You can do it for example like this:

```
this.reload = function () {
    self.list.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        self.list.push(i * 10);
    }
};
```

Angular uses strict object comparison in watchers digest cycle, so when you reset list with `self.list = []` you completely overwrite object reference, so Angular doesn't know that you updated previous it used to render in the list. On the other hand, `this.list.length = 0` is the quick way to clear array, not to *overwrite* with new one, but actually *clear* it.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/fz2zgozx/2/